# Issue with textfields and scrollview

Tags: iphone

I am observing a weird behavior in my app:
My app contains multiple textfields in a scrollview. Now when I click on one textfield to modify it, my "textFieldDidBeginEditing" is called and if I click on Return key of my keyboard "textFieldDidEndEditing" is called and during these operations I am getting my full view in perfect frame of scrollview. 
But problem comes when instead of return button, I click on another textfield in my view then strangely my "textFieldDidEndEditing" is not called and some of my view in scrollview is not scrollable. Something happened to my scrollview's frame.
Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to diagnose without code, or error messages. So recheck your IBOutlets and Delegates to make sure they are connected to the objects you think they should be connected to. If you have both textfields and textviews make sure the delegates are there and everything is hooked up.